# Who are the Peruvian citizens voting from the US?

Tags: presidential-election, peru

While reading the answers to this [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/65851/why-did-keiko-fujimori-overwhelmingly-win-large-us-cities-with-large-peruvian-po) I noticed a point that was largely missed. Who are the Peruvian citizens living in the US who can vote in the Peruvian elections? Would undocumented migants be able to vote? How many of them are member of well off families studying in US universities? How many are legal expatriates with a university degree working in better paid jobs?

Comment: I don't know about Peruvians, but when I was in grad school in the US, I was able to vote in Finnish elections at our closest consulate, and I met several fellow countrymen doing the same. In other words, other Finns temporarily legally residing in the US. I would think most nations have similar arrangements. A possibly better known scenario to the readers of this forum is the personnel of US armed forces currently in a foreign country. They can vote without a trip to the US. You do need to do it in advance, so that the votes can be mailed and counted along with votes cast at home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Peruvian population in the USA numbers about 650 thousand. The majority of these are documented and living legally in the USA. (the number of undocumented Peruvians is difficult to measure exactly, but is likely to be about 10% of Peruvians and less than 1% of all undocumented immigrants). About 40% of Peruvians were born in the USA, And nearly half have been in the USA for 20 years or more.  58% of foreign-born Peruvians have obtained US citizenship (Peru accepts dual citizenship, so the acquisition of US citizenship does not entail the loss of Peruvian citizenship)

32% of Peruvians in the USA have a Bachelor's degree, and the average earnings was around $30000.  This is comparable with the US average and significantly higher than the figures for other Latinx and Hispanic groups.

In theory, undocumented immigrants can vote in Peru. In practice, it is hard to do so, as the immigrant may need to travel to Peru to register, and returning to the USA is not possible for an undocumented immigrant.

https://www.pewresearch.org/hispanic/fact-sheet/u-s-hispanics-facts-on-peruvian-origin-latinos/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is difficult to draw a reliable picture from it though, because the number of votes reported in the question at the origin of this one gives me the feeling that only a small part of the Peruvian residents in the US participated to the presidentiantial election.